# Can you recommed a discrete simulation modelling system (like GPSS or Rockwell Arena) for Linux?

Tags: software-rec

Do you know of a tool for discrete processes (those like production, logistics, client queue service (retail, call center etc.) etc.)) simulation modelling? I am familiar with 2 of such applications for Windows: Rockwell Arena and GPSS World. Are there any free alternatives for Linux? Maybe even standard (BEPL/UML/IDEF0/2/3) aware?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [SimPy](http://simpy.sourceforge.net/).  I haven't used SimPy in maybe 4 years, but I think it could do what you want.  It may be a bit more basic, not including all the bells and whistles that your Windows software does.